# Why Spring Data ignore FetchMode with JPA and how does it works

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data and JPA with Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE, 
I have 3 entities declared like this:
Class A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    private B b;

    //Getters et Setters
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
    private C c;
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "b")
    private List<A> as;
        //Getters et Setters
```

Class C:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "c")
    private List<B> bs;

    //Getters and Setters
```

and added my repositories and services like this :
`ARepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, String> {
}
```

`AService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {

    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;

    @Override
    public List<A> findAll() {
        return aRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

`AController`:

```
@RestController
public class AController {

    @Autowired
    private transient AService aService;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public List<A> test() {

        return aService.findAll();
    }
```

And the last class is `MyApp` for SpringBoot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"fr.dao"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"fr.entities"})
@ComponentScan({"fr.dao",
                "fr.service",
                "fr.web"})
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

When i execute `http://localhost:8080/test`, I want to get all records of `A` with `B` fetched if exist and I want a list of `C` in `B` not initialised (just a proxy).
Also, I want the `FetchMode` `Join` not `Select` in `A` for the item `B`.
But what I got is a select query (there is Join) and Spring Data trying to load all `C` objects in `B`,
and this exception:

```
Hibernate: select a0_.id as id1_0_, a0_.attribute1 as attribute2_0_, a0_.attribute2 as attribute3_0_, a0_.b_id as b_id4_0_ from a a0_
Hibernate: select b0_.id as id1_1_0_, b0_.attribute1 as attribute2_1_0_, b0_.attribute2 as attribute3_1_0_, b0_.c_id as c_id4_1_0_, c1_.id as id1_2_1_, c1_.attribute1 as attribute2_2_1_, c1_.attribute2 as attribute3_2_1_ from b b0_, c c1_ where b0_.c_id=c1_.id(+) and b0_.id=?
Hibernate: select b0_.id as id1_1_0_, b0_.attribute1 as attribute2_1_0_, b0_.attribute2 as attribute3_1_0_, b0_.c_id as c_id4_1_0_, c1_.id as id1_2_1_, c1_.attribute1 as attribute2_2_1_, c1_.attribute2 as attribute3_2_1_ from b b0_, c c1_ where b0_.c_id=c1_.id(+) and b0_.id=?
Hibernate: select b0_.id as id1_1_0_, b0_.attribute1 as attribute2_1_0_, b0_.attribute2 as attribute3_1_0_, b0_.c_id as c_id4_1_0_, c1_.id as id1_2_1_, c1_.attribute1 as attribute2_2_1_, c1_.attribute2 as attribute3_2_1_ from b b0_, c c1_ where b0_.c_id=c1_.id(+) and b0_.id=?
Hibernate: select bs0_.c_id as c_id4_1_0_, bs0_.id as id1_1_0_, bs0_.id as id1_1_1_, bs0_.attribute1 as attribute2_1_1_, bs0_.attribute2 as attribute3_1_1_, bs0_.c_id as c_id4_1_1_ from b bs0_ where bs0_.c_id=?

2017-05-07 22:13:01.347 ERROR 8476 --- [io-8090-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON document: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: fr.entities.B["c"]->fr.entities.C["bs"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->....->fr.entities.B["c"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

Have anyone any idea how I can change my config to get what I want?

Comment: B refers to C, C refers to B again, B and C refer to each other, this is infinite loop.

Comment: The error is not originating in Spring Data but rather in the MVC/REST layer when an object is being serialized (`HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON document`). This is typical of scenarios highlighted by @Forward above involving cyclic loops. Either `B.c` or `C.bs` needs to be annotated with `@JsonIgnore` to avoid the infinite recursion due to the cyclic loop.

Comment: @Forward That is called a BIDIRECTIONAL relation and any JPA provider would be able to handle it. The JSON provider is the only one that needs special treatment for such things

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks, I get it. But I'v known it, what I want to say is a hint to OP, not an answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for comment, it helps me :)
I avoid the infinite recursion with @JsonIgnore and there is no cyclic loop right now, but there is any solution for @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)